# Multiple Media Picker doesn't save after 100 images

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

When I reach the limit (100 images) using Multiple Media Picker (Umbraco 7.2.6), I can't save anymore. I got some errors:

```
http://domain.com/umbraco/backoffice/UmbracoApi/Content/PostSave 500 (Internal Server Error)
TypeError: data.indexOf is not a function
```

How can I turn the limitation off? Or is that a bug?

Comment: I'd suggest that if you're having to pick that many, maybe model your content a little differently. I don't know if the multi media picker has a limitation of 100 (You could ask the developers on the umbraco forums, or the package site)

Comment: If you have to pick that many folders, why not just pick a media folder, and add the images you need to into that folder, then use the api to iterate through that folder?

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I don't think it's a long term solution.

Comment: Your alternative is to get the source for the data type if you can and extend it - a useful exercise, and you could submit a fix into core Umbraco. There's a great page with details how to here - https://our.umbraco.org/contribute

Comment: I tried to find the source and extend it, but I couldn't. Do you have any idea, how can I do it?

Comment: My whole project is based on images.

Comment: I checked the source, but unfortunately I didn't find anything config value

Answer (score 1):

I didn't try yet. But found a solution at his post: [enter link description here](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/questions-about-runway-and-modules/67065-save-problem-after-100-images)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Carl Sargunar, your best bet would be to have all 100 images under a folder and then select that in your picker, then you can use the Umbraco api to retrieve all your images based on the parentId of the folder you have selected on your MNTP.

Regards

Comment: I do agree with everybody and I already implemented this way, but the client doesn't really like it. So is that a way to increase that number?